# Get the audio data from Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assist-api

As of now (is using [api.ai](https://api.ai/)) what I see is, I get the string format of what the user speaks.

I would like to access the raw audio file the user speaks to interact with Google Assistant using the [api.ai](https://api.ai/) platform.

Is there a way to get the audio file ?

[UPDATE]:

We are aiming to evaluate the quality of speech of the user hence we would need to run the algorithms on the audio.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no way to get the audio content of what has been sent.

(However, the team is looking to understand the use cases of why you might want or need this feature, so you may want to elaborate on your question further.)

Comment: As for myself, I would use it to generate an audio dataset.